# Does this look like burn damage

Tags: pcb, damage

I had my plumber change the PCB of my boiler last year. Last week it stopped working and I tried to troubleshoot the problem. The circuit board just doesn't show any sign of life, the ON LED doesn't turn on at all.

On the board I see a brown area. I suspect it has burnt but the damage doesn't look really important, so I would like to check with you if this indeed looks like burnt damage and if that could make the whole PCB dead:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe too much current passed through the resistors and made them heat up too much.Why did you he change it in the first place?Sounds like you are dealing with low quality products.

Comment: The plumber upgraded my hot water cylinder from vented to unvented and he said the old boiler PCB wouldn't work with the new system. I have tried replacing the old PCB and although I see some LED activity, the ignition doesn't work, and he is quite a reputable plumber so I trust him it needed changing. The new PCB is an original replacement part from BAXI - if it is burnt I agree it definitely shows manufacturing defect but I am not sure it is still under some kind of warranty (it was installed 1 year and 2 month ago)

Comment: This is definitely burning (heat) damage, and yes, it can be that the whole PCB is dead because of that. Without a schematic it is impossible to understand why this could have happened. You can try to change the four resistors with identical parts, but it will probably broke again.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three 33 ohm  resistors in series there, (R1,R2,R64) someone did that on purpose, probably because they needed a higher wattage than a single resistor could handle.

That sort of discolouration is fairly common where boards get hot. it does not necessarily indicate a fault.

If the board gets too burnt it can become conductive, your board is part-way there. but I don't think all the way there.

Remove the resistors (R1 R2 R64) and measure the resistance on between the pads where R2 connected, if it shows less than 1 Mega ohm the board is damaged, if not the fault lies elsewhere.
.

Comment: The three resistors in series are R1, R2 and R64. And I'm not sure how you're getting 10k as the value; they look more like 33 or 330 ohms to me. I agree that the PCB itself  is probably still functional, but the resistors might not be.

Comment: where you see gold, I was seeing brown, where you see two orange bands I was seeing one orange and one gold, but now I agree. with you,